# IntelliJ Error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: java, intellij-idea, grails, out-of-memory, memory-overhead

I'm running Grails 2.5.0 on IntelliJ Idea Ultimate Edition 2020.2.2 . It compiles and builds the code just fine but it keeps throwing a "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded" error (the entire error is copy and pasted at the end). Here are the things I've tried based off researching this error:

1.) Increasing build process heap size (tried at 2G, 4G, and 6G)
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003315120-GC-overhead-limit-exceeded

2.) Increasing memory heap size (tried at 2G, 4G, and 6G)
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/increasing-memory-heap.html

3.) Increasing the maximum memory setting for the JVM in the launch configuration (tried at 2G, 4G, and 6G)

I saw that one of the fixes for this error is to "Reuse existing objects when possible to save some memory." However I believe strongly that this is not an issue with the code but with settings on my IDE. The code I am using works fine without errors on the production website and this OutOfMemoryError only appears on my local machine. I would appreciate any help anyone can give, thank you!!!

```
2020-09-21 09:19:56.661 ERROR --- [nio-8805-exec-3] o.s.l.agent.SpringLoadedPreProcessor     : Unexpected problem transforming call sites

org.springsource.loaded.ReloadException: Unexpected problem locating the bytecode for ch/qos/logback/classic/spi/IThrowableProxy.class
    at org.springsource.loaded.TypeRegistry.couldBeReloadable(TypeRegistry.java:775)
    at org.springsource.loaded.TypeRegistry.isReloadableTypeName(TypeRegistry.java:942)
    at org.springsource.loaded.TypeRegistry.isReloadableTypeName(TypeRegistry.java:780)
    at org.springsource.loaded.MethodInvokerRewriter$RewriteClassAdaptor$RewritingMethodAdapter.visitMethodInsn(MethodInvokerRewriter.java:1133)
    at sl.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
    at sl.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source)
    at sl.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at sl.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.springsource.loaded.MethodInvokerRewriter.rewrite(MethodInvokerRewriter.java:348)
    at org.springsource.loaded.MethodInvokerRewriter.rewrite(MethodInvokerRewriter.java:99)
    at org.springsource.loaded.TypeRegistry.methodCallRewriteUseCacheIfAvailable(TypeRegistry.java:1002)
    at org.springsource.loaded.agent.SpringLoadedPreProcessor.preProcess(SpringLoadedPreProcessor.java:361)
    at org.springsource.loaded.agent.ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.transform(ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.java:107)
    at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:428)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:55)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LoggingEvent.<init>(LoggingEvent.java:119)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.buildLoggingEventAndAppend(Logger.java:419)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog_0_Or3Plus(Logger.java:383)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.log(Logger.java:765)
    at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.callLocationAwareLogger(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:221)
    at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.publish(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:303)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:738)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:765)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.logp(Logger.java:1042)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.log(DirectJDKLog.java:182)
    at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.error(DirectJDKLog.java:148)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:251)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:808)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springsource.loaded.TypeRegistry.couldBeReloadable(TypeRegistry.java:718)
    ... 54 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3664)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:207)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(StringBuilder.java:407)
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.resolve(UnixFileSystem.java:108)
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:367)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$FileLoader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:1331)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$FileLoader.findResource(URLClassPath.java:1301)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.findResource(URLClassPath.java:225)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(URLClassLoader.java:572)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(URLClassLoader.java:570)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findResource(URLClassLoader.java:569)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(ClassLoader.java:1096)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springsource.loaded.TypeRegistry.couldBeReloadable(TypeRegistry.java:718)
    at org.springsource.loaded.TypeRegistry.isReloadableTypeName(TypeRegistry.java:942)
    at org.springsource.loaded.TypeRegistry.isReloadableTypeName(TypeRegistry.java:780)
    at org.springsource.loaded.MethodInvokerRewriter$RewriteClassAdaptor$RewritingMethodAdapter.visitMethodInsn(MethodInvokerRewriter.java:1133)
    at sl.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
    at sl.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source)
    at sl.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at sl.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.springsource.loaded.MethodInvokerRewriter.rewrite(MethodInvokerRewriter.java:348)
    at org.springsource.loaded.MethodInvokerRewriter.rewrite(MethodInvokerRewriter.java:99)
    at org.springsource.loaded.TypeRegistry.methodCallRewriteUseCacheIfAvailable(TypeRegistry.java:1002)
    at org.springsource.loaded.agent.SpringLoadedPreProcessor.preProcess(SpringLoadedPreProcessor.java:361)
    at org.springsource.loaded.agent.ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.transform(ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.java:107)
    at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:428)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)

2020-09-21 09:19:57.566 ERROR --- [nio-8805-exec-3] .a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[grailsDispatcherServlet] : Servlet.service() for servlet [grailsDispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException: null
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.rethrowRuntimeException(ReflectionUtils.java:316)
    at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequest.<init>(GrailsWebRequest.java:106)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.access.intercept.AnnotationFilterInvocationDefinition.determineUrl(AnnotationFilterInvocationDefinition.groovy:106)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.access.intercept.AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition.getAttributes(AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition.groovy:75)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:197)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:124)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsHttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsHttpPutFormContentFilter.groovy:54)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at javax.servlet.FilterChain$doFilter.call(Unknown Source)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestTokenValidationFilter.processFilterChain(RestTokenValidationFilter.groovy:121)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestTokenValidationFilter.doFilter(RestTokenValidationFilter.groovy:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RestAuthenticationFilter.groovy:139)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.groovy:64)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityRequestHolderFilter.groovy:58)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:808)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrConstructorNewInstance(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1076)
    at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequest.<init>(GrailsWebRequest.java:102)
    ... 63 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.copy(Method.java:153)
    at java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.copyMethod(ReflectAccess.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.copyMethod(ReflectionFactory.java:316)
    at java.lang.Class.copyMethods(Class.java:3124)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1615)
    at java.beans.MethodRef.find(MethodRef.java:76)
    at java.beans.MethodRef.get(MethodRef.java:62)
    at java.beans.PropertyDescriptor.getReadMethod(PropertyDescriptor.java:207)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.applyPropertyDescriptors(MetaClassImpl.java:2527)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setupProperties(MetaClassImpl.java:2265)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.addProperties(MetaClassImpl.java:3338)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.initialize(MetaClassImpl.java:3303)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClassUnderLock(ClassInfo.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClass(ClassInfo.java:331)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClass(ClassInfo.java:341)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.getMetaClass(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:281)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getMetaClass(InvokerHelper.java:901)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePojoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:934)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:926)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.castToBoolean(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:198)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.booleanUnbox(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:87)
    at org.grails.web.context.ServletEnvironmentGrailsApplicationDiscoveryStrategy.findApplicationContext(ServletEnvironmentGrailsApplicationDiscoveryStrategy.groovy:61)
    at grails.util.Holders.findApplicationContext(Holders.java:106)
    at org.grails.web.servlet.DefaultGrailsApplicationAttributes.<init>(DefaultGrailsApplicationAttributes.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrConstructorNewInstance(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1076)
    at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequest.<init>(GrailsWebRequest.java:102)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.access.intercept.AnnotationFilterInvocationDefinition.determineUrl(AnnotationFilterInvocationDefinition.groovy:106)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.access.intercept.AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition.getAttributes(AbstractFilterInvocationDefinition.groovy:75)

Exception in thread "http-nio-8805-exec-3" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Comment: Only 3) will make sense here. Can you show the screenshot of the run/debug configuration with the correct memory setting?

Comment: Sure thing! [Screenshot Images here](https://imgur.com/a/tgliQNe)  These are the two different configurations I've tried. Let me know if you need any other information!

Comment: Why do you have `$` at the end of the option on the first screenshot?

Comment: Whoops, I'm sorry that's a typo when I was manually re-entering it in for the screenshot. It was definitely supposed to be just "-Xmx6G". I tested both just now (without typos) and I still hit the error again. Would appreciate any insight, thank you!

Comment: Try adding these options as well in the VM Options field of the run configuration: `-XX:MaxPermSize=700m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=480m`.

Answer (score 22):

The simplest possible solution could be, increase the build process heap size as shown below. Definitely this would help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me and build ok.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try to increase compiler heap size.
[image]